# Draw Bezier Curve using DeCasteljau Algorithm using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how to draw Bezier Curve using deCasteljau algorithm where the user input N custom point. For example when the user touch on the screen, it create a point and when the next point is created, a line is drawn in between. The problem I face is I only manage to draw the Bezier Curve with four N point present. How to continue the Bezier Curve depends on the number of N points using the algorithm. I am still new to Swift so any help is welcome.

For now I set the control point to be fixed position.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import GLKit

 //Class to store the x and y coordinates
 class point_arr{   
    var x:CGFloat=0 
    var y:CGFloat=0  
 }

 public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
     return UIScreen.main.bounds.width

 }

  public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
     return UIScreen.main.bounds.height

 }

 class ViewController: GLKViewController {

private var context: EAGLContext?
var lastPosition: CGPoint?
var point_count :Int = 0
//var points = Array<Array<CGPoint>>() // Store array of CGPoints

//To store the position of the coordinates
var points:[point_arr] = []
var position_x: CGFloat = 0
var position_y: CGFloat = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    EAGLcontext()
    // Gesture Code
 }

// Touch Function
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{

        let position = touch.location(in: view)
        if let lastPosition = self.lastPosition {
            self.drawLineFromPoint(start: lastPosition, toPoint: position, ofColor: UIColor.red, inView: self.view)
        }
        self.lastPosition = position
        // View the x and y coordinates
        let dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: 10, height: 10))
        dot.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(dot)

        position_x=position.x
        position_y=position.y

        //Assign the point_array
        let dots = point_arr()
        dots.x = position_x
        dots.y = position_y
        points.append(dots)

        print("Position :",points[point_count].x,",",points[point_count].y)
        point_count+=1
        print("Number of points : ", point_count)
        print(points)

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first, let lastPosition = self.lastPosition{

        let position = touch.location(in: view)
        self.drawLineFromPoint(start: lastPosition, toPoint: position, ofColor: UIColor.red, inView: self.view)
        self.lastPosition = position
        let dot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: position.x, y: position.y, width: 10, height: 10))
        dot.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(dot)

    }
}

//calculation for Bezier curve
func calculateBezier(point p1:CGPoint, andPoint p2:CGPoint, point_count:Int) {

    //Testing Purposes
    //for t in stride(from: 0, to: 1, by: 0.125){}
    //print(p1.x,p1.y)
    //print(p2.x,p2.y)
    //print("Number of points: ",point_count)
    //print(points)
    //print("Factorial of N:",factorial(n: point_count))

    //Do the calculation here


}


//factorial recursive function
func factorial ( n:Int)->Int   {

    var ans = n
    if (ans<=1) {
        return (1)
    }
    else {
        ans = ans * (factorial(n:n - 1))
    }
    return ans
}

func binomial_coff(n:Int , i:Int)->Int{

    var ans:Int
    ans = factorial(n: n) / (factorial(n: n - i) * factorial(n: i))
    return ans

}


//Draw line from point to point
func drawLineFromPoint(start : CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint, ofColor lineColor: UIColor, inView view:UIView) {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: start)
    path.addLine(to: end)

    //Draw the bezier curve taking two control points.
    if(points.count>3){
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: points[0].x, y: points[0].y ))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: position_x , y: position_y),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: points[1].x , y: points[1].y), // This CP is fixed so need to change
                      controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: points[2].x , y: points[2].y)
        )

    }

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}


//Create EAGL Context for the GLKView
private func EAGLcontext() {

    context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)

    EAGLContext.setCurrent(context)

    if let view = self.view as? GLKView, let context = context {

        view.context = context
        delegate = self
    }
}

override func glkView(_ view: GLKView, drawIn rect: CGRect) {
    //Set the color
    glClearColor(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1.0)
    glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    }
}
extension ViewController: GLKViewControllerDelegate {
func glkViewControllerUpdate(_ controller: GLKViewController) {

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }
```

The expected result is the more points the user created, the curve continue to be drawn using the algorithm.

Comment: If a user sets 7 points, are they supposed to be the start point, two control points, a joint start/end point, another two control points and an end point for a total of two bezier segments? Or how is this supposed to work? What if the user only sets three points? What should be drawn?

Comment: https://img-blog.csdn.net/20160625161809847
This is for 5 point for example
https://img-blog.csdn.net/20160625160903288
This is the result of 3 points.

So basically the end result for the bezier curve will be like the image below 
https://img-blog.csdn.net/20160625161912098

Comment: You probably want to look at `addQuadCurve`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624351-addquadcurve

Comment: @DonMag I have looked it but I only manage to use two control points for now. The function take two control point. What I wanted is to take custom points from user to generate the bezier curve using the algorithm

Comment: @RoshanDx - have you also looked at `func addCurve(to endPoint: CGPoint, controlPoint1: CGPoint, controlPoint2: CGPoint)`? I think you'll need to start writing some code to implement what you're trying to do, and see how far you get. There is definitely no built-in function *"add curves to **n** points"*.

Comment: I have tried some coding but the end result was wrong.

Comment: @RoshanDx - are you trying to reproduce those animations? Or the end-result curve? It's not at all clear what you are asking... Try editing your question with plain language describing what you want, e.g. *"The user taps once, I want this output. On second tap, it should look like this. On third tap, this. On fourth tap, this. On fifth tap, this."* and so on.

Comment: @DonMag It's like this, the user tap on the screen it creates a red dot. There is no need of the animation just the bezier curve to be drawn from the start to the end point. For example, if user create three red dot on the screen, a bezier curve will be drawn as shown in the diagram https://img-blog.csdn.net/20160625160903288

If the user creates five points, then the bezier curve will be drawn as in the diagram https://img-blog.csdn.net/20160625160903288. I just need the end result curve. Hope this answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: @RoshanDx - still not clear... What happens on the 4th tap? What if the user taps 4 vertical points? For 5 taps, what if the user taps left - right - left - right - center?

Comment: @DonMag If user tap 4 point vertical then the user gets a straight bezier. If 5 taps left - right - left - right - center then it gets something like in the diagram .You can play with the points at here. My end result is similar to this. At the bottom of the page is the demo to be played with. Hope this helps you. https://www.cnblogs.com/leee/p/9133013.html?fbclid=IwAR2p0-ATsFA_wbws-I7UEioXlHqjvbl1WKRK4lQ9o0mwjMqedx6CljD7s2s

Comment: @RoshanDx - OK... this is more of a logic question than a Swift / iOS / programming question. With `UIBezierPath` you will probably want to add multiple curves, and you may have to calculate the control points (as opposed to simply using the user points). As to the link you gave, I can't read the page, but it *looks* like it's pretty much explaining everything, including providing the javascript code being used. Maybe dig through that to get the logic / calculations, and then apply that to writing it in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Casteljau` class add in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hadiidbouk/e3dc6c9bcdfead361acaebb4498826c6).

Usage:

```swift
 let casteljau = Casteljau(p0: p0, p1: p1, p2: p2, p3: p3)
 let numberOfPoints = 16
 for i in 0..< numberOfPoints {
     let t = Double(i) / Double(numberOfPoints - 1)
     let point = casteljau.point(at: CGFloat(t))
 }
```